# JavaScript oninput listener is not working unless I wait 1000 ms

Tags: javascript, timing

This function below runs when the element with class `blockUI` disappears from frontend:

```
function auto_stock_sum_on_input() {
  var dad = $('.woocommerce_variations.wc-metaboxes.ui-sortable'); //it's just to identify easier the desired element
  var descendants = dad.find('.custom-variation-fields-container');
  descendants.on('input', function() { //adding a event listener to sum all input values from some children
    store_stock = $(this).find('.custom-field');
    stock_variation_sum = 0
    store_stock.each(function() { //summing values from such children
      stock_variation_sum = stock_variation_sum + parseInt($(this).val(), 10);
    });
    $(this).closest('.woocommerce_variation.wc-metabox').find('.short.wc_input_stock').val(stock_variation_sum); //storing the sum in this element
  });
}
```

The problem is the oninput event is just being detected if I wait 1 second (1000ms) after `.blockUI` element disappears.

I debbugged it by console.log, I found out even if descendants has input tags as children the oninput event is not triggered when user fills input with something, I must wait 1000ms after `.blockUI` element disappears to the event gets triggered. I also tried the boolean test `onipunt` is in there and returned true when not waiting 1000ms. I'd like the code runs fine without setting a time out. What can cause this issue?

PS: `.blockUI` is just a element to block UX when data is being fetch.

Comment: Don't add and remove event listeners when the DOM changes. Instead, have the event listener check whether the `.blockUI` element exists, and return immediately.